# "__defineGetter__(0x1000, () => 1)", what does mean?

Tags: javascript

How is `__defineGetter__(0x1000, () => 1)` valid?

The first argument of `__defineGetter__` should be a property, and the second argument a function.

Is 0x1000 a valid property name? or does `__defineGetter__` accept something else as a first agument?

Comment: `0x1000` is a number, in the hexadecimal numbering system. `0x1 == 1` and `0x10 == 16`. any number or string can be used as property.

Comment: actually, the numbers will convert to string when used as properties though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although confusing, `0x1000` is indeed a valid property.

```
let x = {}
x.__defineGetter__(0x1000, () => 1)
x[0x1000] // == x['4096'] == 1
```

More generally though, object property keys are strings, and if you use something that is not a string, it will be converted to one using `String(key)`. A more explicit example:

```
let x = {}
let y = {}
x.__defineGetter__(y, () => 1)
x[y] // == x['[object Object]'] == 1
```

Consequently, if the string representation of two different  values (e.g. two different objects) is not the same, they will act as the **same** key (and map to the same value).

Comment: You should add a note that the property name is not actually the integer `0x1000` but rather the string `"4096"`